# Proper usage of `tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device()` with a feedable iterator

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'd like to know if it's possible (and if so, how?) to use a `tf.data.Dataset` object to which `tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device()` has been applied with a feedable iterator. My original unoptimized Dataset definition is:

```
training_dataset_shuffle_batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data).shuffle(dataset_size).repeat().batch(minibatch_size).prefetch(minibatch_size)
training_shuffle_batch_iterator = training_dataset_shuffle_batch.make_initializable_iterator()
```

and I've rewritten that to

```
training_dataset_shuffle_batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data)
training_dataset_shuffle_batch = training_dataset_shuffle_batch.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size = dataset_size))
training_dataset_shuffle_batch = training_dataset_shuffle_batch.batch(minibatch_size)
training_dataset_shuffle_batch = training_dataset_shuffle_batch.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device(gpu_names[0]))
training_shuffle_batch_iterator = training_dataset_shuffle_batch.make_initializable_iterator()
```

because I'm running this on an AWS p3.2xlarge instance with a GPU, so I'd like to prefect data into the GPU for efficiency gains. 
In either version my iterator and data fetcher are defined as

```
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, training_dataset_shuffle_batch.output_types, training_dataset_shuffle_batch.output_shapes) 
next_input_data_element = iterator.get_next()
```

Later I try to get a handle for `training_shuffle_batch_iterator` via `training_shuffle_batch_handle = sess.run(training_shuffle_batch_iterator.string_handle())`
to use with `iterator` (there are other Dataset object iterators that I want to pull data from when using `next_input_data_element`). While things are fine when I use the first Dataset definition, the second fails with an `AttributeError: '_PrefetchToDeviceIterator' object has no attribute 'string_handle'` error.

Am I doing this right and this just isn't supported, or is there a mistake in my approach? This is using TF V1.8.0. Thank you.